# Finding triggers/constraints in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, triggers

Somewhere in my database there is a trigger/constraint that creates a row in a table called `emailers_run`. It's probably when a batch email has been run. But I can't find any triggers in those associated tables. Any ideas on how I can tracks this process down?

Comment: Do you have access to visual studio? If so, you can reverse engineer the schema into a database project and simply search for occurrences of that table name

Comment: Well, by reverse engineering,  I found that the one column in question had a default value of getdate().  No triggers or constraints.  That might be the only default value in the entire database. I could have just looked at the column defs.  But you got me there in spite of myself.  many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking dependencies in management studio you can use SQL Server Profiler to track down your problem. I hope this will help you.

Comment: It's something we can fix :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Pradhan: Disagree, this does attempt to answer the question "Any ideas on how I can tracks this process down?".